# Simple progress dialog onClick and hide when finish operation

Tags: java, android, progressdialog, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I want show a progress dialog  (with a progressbar or circle this is indifferent to me) when i click the button. Actually i can show it but i don't know how hide it after finish the operations inside at onclick. This is the code:

```
copy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
            public void onClick(View v){

                                ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                                progressDialog.setProgressStyle(R.style.NewDialog);
                                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                                progressDialog.show(); 
                                String datafolder = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"app";
                                File customfolder=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()+File.separator+"BackupApps");
                                String comando = "cp -r /data/app /sdcard/BackupApps";
                                Process suProcess = null;
                                try {
                                    suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                                } catch (IOException e3) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e3.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());

                                try {

                                    os.writeBytes(comando + "\n");

                                } catch (IOException e2) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e2.printStackTrace();

                                }
                                try {
                                    os.flush();
                                } catch (IOException e1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                try {
                                    os.writeBytes("exit\n");

                                } catch (IOException e1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                try {
                                    os.flush();

                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();

                                }   

                            }


        });
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Use AsynchTask for this..show your dialog in the onPreExecute and dismiss it in onPostExecute..

Comment: Can you help me and show how could i do it please?

Comment: ok..wait i will post my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define inner class like this in your class

```
    class SaveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(R.style.NewDialog);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String datafolder = Environment.getDataDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "app";
        File customfolder = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()
                + File.separator + "BackupApps");
        String comando = "cp -r /data/app /sdcard/BackupApps";
        Process suProcess = null;
        try {
            suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        } catch (IOException e3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(
                suProcess.getOutputStream());

        try {

            os.writeBytes(comando + "\n");

        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();

        }
        try {
            os.flush();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            os.writeBytes("exit\n");

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            os.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (progressDialog != null) {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

call this in your onClick() like this..
here we haven't passing any data to AsynchTask so here i am passing null

```
copy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
            public void onClick(View v){
    SaveTask task = new SaveTask();
    task.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: So in the onClick something like: `public void onClick(View v){
    YourAsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask(context);
    asyncTask.execute();
}`? All inside at the `onCreate`?

Comment: inside onClick it is correct but the class is not inside onCreate its outside of your onCreate() method..

Answer (score 1):

Start a AsyncTask on onClick method like this:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    YourAsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask(context);
    asyncTask.execute();
}
```

And in your AsyncTask create a ProgressDialog on onPreExecute(), do your stuff in doInBackground() and dismiss the ProgressDialog on onPostExecute():

```
public class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private Context ctx;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public YourAsyncTask(Context ctx) {
      this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
  ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
      progressDialog.setProgressStyle(R.style.NewDialog);
      progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
      progressDialog.show(); 
}


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                 String datafolder = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"app";
                 File customfolder=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()+File.separator+"BackupApps");
                 String comando = "cp -r /data/app /sdcard/BackupApps";
                 Process suProcess = null;
                 try {
                       suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                 } catch (IOException e3) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                      e3.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());

                            try {

                                os.writeBytes(comando + "\n");

                            } catch (IOException e2) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e2.printStackTrace();

                            }
                            try {
                                os.flush();
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            try {
                                os.writeBytes("exit\n");

                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            try {
                                os.flush();

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();

                            }   

                        }
    }
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void res) {
      progressDialog.hide();
      progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: inside or outside the `onCreate`?

Comment: I'm working in a fragment.. I don't know if the onClick is permitted

Comment: The onClick method must be inside your OnClickListener, like you did in your question.

Answer (score 1):

don't foget to declare the progressDialog global variable

```
 @Override 
public void onClick(View v) {
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                progressDialog.setProgressStyle(R.style.NewDialog);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        String datafolder = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"app";
                            File customfolder=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()+File.separator+"BackupApps");
                            String comando = "cp -r /data/app /sdcard/BackupApps";
                            Process suProcess = null;
                            try {
                                suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                            } catch (IOException e3) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e3.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());

                            try {

                                os.writeBytes(comando + "\n");

                            } catch (IOException e2) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e2.printStackTrace();

                            }
                            try {
                                os.flush();
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            try {
                                os.writeBytes("exit\n");

                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            try {
                                os.flush();

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();

                            }   
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (progressDialog!=null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

};
task.execute((Void[])null);
```

}

Comment: All inside at the `onCreate`?

Comment: I'm working in a fragment.. I don't know if the `onClick` is permitted

Comment: copy my onClick() method code to inside of your onClick() method

Comment: you said earlier.. your code of on click is working but only you want to know how to dismiss the progress dialog.. isn't it.. 
so what you wanna do now is.. just replace your onClick() method body with my onClick() method body..

Comment: feel free to ask anything.. i'm here.. :)

Comment: oook, but `pd`...what is?

Comment: Do you think is possible insert the completion percentage?

Answer (score 0):

Add `progressDialog.dismiss();` in the last line on `onClick` and in all the `catch` so that it will disappear even if an `Exception` is thrown